# { useUnifiedTopology: true } Pass deprecated

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Why i need to pass { useUnifiedTopology: true } in my app.js .When i dont't pass the { useUnifiedTopology: true } still everything works. SO is it okay to not pass it in my server file.
Is it going to effect my project.

Answer (score 2):

There are several deprecations in the MongoDB Node.js driver that Mongoose users should be aware of. Mongoose provides options to work around these deprecation warnings, but you need to test whether these options cause any problems for your application.

MongoDB driver 3.3.x, which introduced a significant refactor of how it handles monitoring all the servers in a replica set or sharded cluster. In MongoDB parlance, this is known as server discovery and monitoring.

To opt in to using the new topology engine, uses the below line:

```
('useUnifiedTopology', true);
```

The useUnifiedTopology option removes support for several connection options that are no longer relevant with the new topology engine:

1. autoReconnect
2. reconnectTries
3. reconnectInterval

When you enable useUnifiedTopology, please remove those options from your mongoose.connect() or createConnection() calls.

Reference: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/deprecations.html